# I need help on finding out what this means. I know there are 4 steps to it.

Tags: riddle, cipher

The driven ambitious with passionate zeal, 
Will step forward to discover the author’s reveal, 
With princes by men, 
In columns of ten, 
the experience the answer shall seal.

QBOKD KWLSDSYX SC DRO ZKCCSYX YP K QBOKD MRKBKMDOB. DRYCO OXNYGON GSDR SD WKI ZOBPYBW FOBI QYYN YB FOBI LKN KMDC. KVV NOZOXNC YX DRO ZBSXMSZVOC GRSMR NSBOMD DROW.

KWLSDSYXMRKVVOXQO NYD GYBNZBOCC NYD MYW

Comment: So what's the broader challenge, Daniel?

Comment: the challenge is to decode this somehow and find out the rest of the riddle

Comment: OK, but where have you got the puzzle from? Who's set up the website? Are there other related puzzles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy. The text is a cryptogram. Plug it in [here](http://quipqiup.com/index.php). It returns:

> GREAT AMBITION IS THE PASSION OF A GREAT CHARACTER. THOSE ENDOWED WITH IT MAY PERFORM VERY GOOD OR VERY BAD ACTS. ALL DEPENDS ON THE PRINCIPLES WHICH DIRECT THEM.  AMBITIONCHALLENGE DOT WORDPRESS DOT COM

Go there. Password is "Napoleon" - the source of the quote.

I can only assume this is part of a broader challenge, as the text there makes little sense to me and doesn't seem to be anything more than a contextual clue. Of course, I could be missing something, too.

Comment: yes it is. please try and figure it out.

Comment: i need help figuring out what i need to do next. i heard that i had to answer a question of some sort. but not sure what it is.

Comment: @Daniel Unfortunately, a wall of text isn't much to go on. At some point, I'd just be guessing what might work. There's nothing to deduce, from at this point.

Comment: Given the quoted text is by (or claims to be by) Francis Bacon, it would perhaps be worth checking for the Baconian cipher. Also: (perhaps irrelevant) Tiberius is Captain Kirk's middle name.